# Ipsilateral vs contralateral side of body

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-anatomy, brain, anatomy

I know that the dorsal columns carry ipsilateral information. Is this fact relative to the dorsal column in question? 
If I want to talk about the right dorsal column, then the right side of the body would be considered ispilateral. But, if i then go on to talk about the left dorsal column, does this mean that the left side of the body is now considered ipsilateral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Ipsilateral and contralateral always have to be *relative to something*; ipsilateral means "same side" and contralateral means "other side" - you can't really be the same or other side of something unless you have a reference point.